# Scala: Case classes with shared parameter?

Tags: scala

I don't know if there's a way to do this, but I want to be able to specify that a set of case classes all share a parameter (so I can access it without pattern matching).

EDIT: After some help I have

```
abstract class Test(val termName : String)
case class TestOne(value : Int, name : String = null) extends Test(name)
case class TesTwo(otherValue : Boolean, name : String = null) extends Test(name)
```

Which is almost exactly what I want, though it would be nice to get rid of the ugliness of having both `name` and `termName`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> though it would be nice to get rid of the ugliness of having both name and termName.

Just make it a normal member of the supertype (which can easily be a `trait`), not a constructor parameter:

```
trait Test { 
  val name : String 
}
case class TestOne(value : Int, name : String = null) extends Test
case class TestTwo(otherValue : Boolean, name : String = null) extends Test
```

(The standard Scala style is `name: String`, no space before `:`.)

Answer (score 3):

If every implementation should have a separate, distinct implementation, declare abstract member and implement it in children:

```
abstract trait NamedCaseClass {
  def name: String
}
case class OneCase(number : Int) extends NamedCaseClass {
  override def name: String = "OneCase"
}
case class OtherCase(truth : Boolean) extends NamedCaseClass {
  override def name: String = "OtherCase"
}
```

If all implementations could just use some value that you can calculate on creation, you can use abstract class constructor:

```
abstract class NamedCaseClass(val name: String)
case class OneCase(number : Int) extends NamedCaseClass("OneCase")
case class OtherCase(truth : Boolean) extends NamedCaseClass("OtherCase")
```

If you have a `sealed` hierarchy you could also define it like this:

```
sealed trait NamedCaseClass {
  def nameOpt: Option[String] = this match {
    case OneCase(number) => Some(name.toString)
    case OtherCase(_)    => None
  }
}
case class OneCase(number : Int) extends NamedCaseClass
case class OtherCase(truth : Boolean) extends NamedCaseClass
```

Which one is more convenient pretty much depend on if you have a sealed hierarchy or open, if you can calculate value on creation or is this something more complicated that would work better as a method.

Comment: You can also use: **typeclasses** _(maybe an overkill, especially if you control all the classes)_ and **structural types** _(requires reflection, which makes it slower and non-portable, but requires less syntactical noise)_

Comment: Thanks... I think option 2 is almost exactly what I want, though I need to be able to specify the name on an instance by instance basis. I edited my question with my current attempt, would you mind taking a look and telling me if there's a way to improve it?